# XNA - Restore focus to a fullscreen XNA game

Tags: c#, xna, focus, fullscreen

I have an XNA Game Project being developed that has a problem when running in fullscreen with two monitors.  Whenever an XBox 360 controller is disconnected or connected while the game is running, the XBox 360 accessories software pops up a message in Windows, forcing the game to minimize and lose focus.  In instances when a game is currently being played and not in the main menu, I need to prevent the game from minimizing itself, and pop up a message displaying certain instances, such as when a controller gets disconnected, from within the game itself, just like it does in other games.

When the game is running windowed, I have no problems bringing the game back to focus.

```
private void GameFocus() {
#if WINDOWS
    // Is the game currently focused and displayed? (Works both fullscreen and windowed)
    if (!IsActive) {
        Windows.Form myForm = (Windows.Form)Windows.Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);

        // Is game not running in full screen?
        if (!graphics.IsFullScreen) {
            if (myForm.WindowState == Windows.FormWindowState.Minimized)
                myForm.WindowState = Windows.FormWindowState.Normal;
            else
                myForm.Focus();
        }
        else {
            // What code goes here?
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

The problem is when the game is running in fullscreen mode.  The state of the window is returning the wrong values.  Whenever I check the windowstate, it is always set to normal.  Whenever I check if the form has focus, it is always true.  Finally, it was suggested on another forum post to try these method calls.

```
myForm.Activate();
myForm.Show();
myForm.Focus();
myForm.Select();
```

None of these method calls worked.

I appreciate in advance any possible solutions.  As an additional note, I already have a pop-up that displays in the game when a controller is disconnected.  I need the game to not minimize in fullscreen when this happens, and a method to bring the game back if this occurs.

Comment: After pondering this question over a bit, I realized it makes sense why the form is no longer correct.  When the game is fullscreen, the form is no longer responsible for rendering the game.

The question I should ask is what is responsible so I can tell it to return focus?  If there is no way for me to accomplish this, then preventing the game from being alt-tabbed out of should not be possible like it is with other games.  I would like to avoid this route if at all possible.